# AVAudioPlayer initializes fine, but refuses to play

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have a curious problem with the `AVAudioPlayer` class. I create a player, get a non-nil reference from the initializer, but the `-play` message returns `NO` and the player doesn’t play. I have implemented the player delegate methods and `-audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:error:` is not called. The error from the initializer is not set.

I have checked the usual suspects. I do set the audio session category, I also activate it. The audio file for the player is recorded by the app just before playing. When I initialize the player with a different sound (from the app bundle), it plays. When I copy the recorded file into the app bundle and then initialize the player with this copy, it plays. When I check for file existence before loading it, the file is there, is readable and has a non-zero size.

I have tried both the Simulator and the device, no difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: what kind of audio file is it? is the different sound the same kind of audio format as the one you're trying to play? if you somehow export the file you recorded (e.g. mail it to yourself), can you play it on your desktop machine (i.e. is it a problem with the actual file and not with the AVAudioPlayer)?

Comment: When you initialize the player with the URL, does it return an error?

Comment: The audio file is a WAV. As I already wrote in the question, I can take the very same file, copy it to the app bundle and it plays just fine from there. (Just as it does when I open it using a different app on my desktop.) The initialization returns no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped to wait 1/10 of a second between the end of recording and playback:

```
dispatch_time_t moment = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1e8);
dispatch_after(moment, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [statusLabel setText:@"Playing"];
    [self setPlayer:[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
        initWithContentsOfURL:[self recordingURL]
        error:NULL]];
    [player play];
});
```

This of course is not a proper solution, so after a bit of searching I realized I wasn’t properly finishing the recording, leaving the file buffers unflushed before creating the player. Now that I flush the buffers before calling the player everything works fine.